# C++ concurrency in action

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-model, stdatomic

This is a question about the memory order listed in 'c++ concurrency in action'.

First, in listing 5.7; the consequence can be:

> Thread A : `x.store(true, release)`
>
> Thread B : `x.load(acquire)` returns true, `y.load(acquire)` returns false
>
> Thread C : `y.load(acquire)` returns true, `x.load(acquire)` returns false
>
> Thread D : `y.store(true, release)`

On the other hand, by 'release sequence':

- thread A's store -> thread B's x_load and
- by release sequence, -> thread C's x_load
- so thread C's x_load must be true, if thread B's y_load is false.

So I think it should be

> Thread B : `x.load(acquire)` returns true, `y.load(acquire)` returns true
>
> Thread C : `y.load(acquire)` returns true, `x.load(acquire)` returns false

or

> Thread B : `x.load(acquire)` returns true, `y.load(acquire)` returns false
>
> Thread C : `y.load(acquire)` returns true, `x.load(acquire)` returns true

Another question:

In listing 7.12 there is a paragraph,

> 'the easy way to do this is to make the `fetch_add()` in the
>   successful-return branch use `std::memory_order_release` and the
>   `fetch_add()` in the loop-again branch use `std::memory_order_acquire`.
>   However, this is still overkill: only one thread does the delete , so
>   only that thread needs to do an acquire operation. Thankfully, because
>   `fetch_add()` is read-modify-write operation, it forms part of the
>   ***release sequence***, so you can do that with an additional `load()`.'

I don't know what this paragraph means; where is the '***release sequence***' ?

Comment: "where is the 'release sequence' ?   
- in listing 7.12 where you see: 
if(ptr->internal_count.fetch_add(count_increase,
 std::memory_order_release)==-count_increase)
 {
 delete ptr;
 }return res;
...

Comment: i thought the release sequence does act like a ***chaining***. if thread A which deletes the node in the stack sends a release memory order to other threads (thread B, thread C), the thread B or C receives the release memory order in the 'ptr->internal_count.load(std::memory_order_acquire) ' and again sends release memory order to other threads. but i think there is no reason why the thread B or C sends the release memory order again.please tell me what's wrong .,

Comment: Your primary question was [asked and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48383867/acquire-release-semantics-with-4-threads/48386173).